# Getting my information to do display in the Google Knowledge Graph

Tags: seo, search-engine, google-search, freebase

I am responsible for maintaining the web site of a Music Festival. Recently, I discovered Google Knowledge Graph. When user's search for the Music Festival by name in Google, I want my information to appear on the right hand panel (the knowledge graph). e.g. the festival dates, location, etc...

How do I get my information into the Knowledge Graph and instruct Google to display it on the search results page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google primarily uses Freebase.com, which is user-editable, however, from what I've seen, Google seems to require that items entities have Wikipedia articles connected with them.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you mark up your events with structured data such as schemas, specifically the schema.org/MusicEvent markup.  And it would also be beneficial to include Open Graph tags on the page as well.

Comment: I also discovered freebase.com which allows you to add information of any type to an open database that Google will reference.

Answer (score 0):

check out wikidata. wikipedias project to centralise all their data. or the mediawiki api.

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php